# Не получается интегрировать Facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebooksdk

При добавлении строки compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)' в dependencies (build.gradle(Module: app)) проект при сборке выводит следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня так:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.4.2@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Если добавить compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0', появляется ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что за странный номер версии у вас стоит у facebook-sdk `[4,5)`? Попробуйте поставить `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'`

Comment: eugeneek, не получилось, я обновила вопрос

Comment: Если прописать com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5) тогда надо все библиотеки обновить до 7.27.0.1. У вас там целый список библиотек до каких версий надо обновить.

Comment: ruslan, а какую версию тогда надо взять, чтобы не обновлять все библиотеки?

Comment: `mavenCentral()` в  `buildscript { repositories {}}` добавляли? Пройдитесь по пунктам ответа ниже, может, что-то упустили.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте по этому ответу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/764409/266476

В частности:

> В своем проекте откройте `your_app` -> `Gradle Scripts` ->
>   `build.gradle (Project)` и добавьте следующий репозиторий в раздел
>   `buildscript { repositories {}}`, чтобы скачать SDK с Maven Central
>   Repository:
>
> ```
> mavenCentral()
> ```