# Как настроить приложение Android для работы с Facebook SDK?

Tags: android, facebook-api, facebooksdk

Как подключить Facebook SDK к своему приложению? Как зарегистрировать приложение на https://developers.facebook.com ? Как начать работу с Facebook SDK?

Comment: На сколько я понял теперь не надо вводить ни имя пакета, ни активити, ни Key Hash. Кстати может сможете подсказать, не могу никак отправить им платежные реквизиты, пишут в данный момент не могут принять платежные данные, не пойму в чем проблема может быть.

Comment: По поводу платежей ничего не подскажу, не сталкивался. По поводу изменений, на https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts ничего не поменялось. В примерах на https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/samples - тоже все по-старому.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Минимальная настройка проекта для начала работы с SDK Facebook [согласно документации](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/componentsdks):

**1)** В своем проекте откройте `your_app` -> `Gradle Scripts` -> `build.gradle (Project)` и добавьте следующий репозиторий в раздел `buildscript { repositories {}}`, чтобы скачать SDK с Maven Central Repository:

```
mavenCentral()
```

**2)** Теперь в `build.gradle (Module: app)` добавляем инструкции компиляции в раздел `dependencies{}` библиотеки необходимые для работы с Facebook:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
```

или для `Gradle` от `v3.0`:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
```

`implementation` - чтобы не тянуть на компиляцию все зависимости, подробнее о разнице `compile` и `implementation` см. [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

**3)** В файле манифеста (`AndroidManifest.xml`), перед тегом `<application>` объявляем разрешение на доступ к сети интернет:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**4)** Теперь внутри `<application>` добавляем `ApplicationId`:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

**5)** Прописываем внутри тегов `<activity> <intent-filter> …` схему (тип) данных, которые будет принимать `Activity`:

```
<data android:scheme="@string/facebook_login_protocol_scheme" />
```

**6)** В `res/values/strings.xml` добавим две строчки, значения (т.е. `ApplicationId` и схему данных) в которые пропишем позднее:

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">add late</string>
<string name="facebook_login_protocol_scheme">add late</string>
```

**7)** Теперь получим *Key Hash* в формате *Base64* согласно [данной документации](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/?locale=ru_RU). В `Activity` временно пишем код:

```
//...
public final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...

    printKeyHash();
}

private void printKeyHash() {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo("io.github.ziginsider.facebooksdkdemo",
                        PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature:info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d(TAG, "KeyHash: " + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
//...
```

**8**) Запускаем приложение и в логах находим Key Hash:

[image: Key Hash]

**9**) Если вы еще не зарегистрированы как разработчик на Facebook, то заходим на сайт [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com) и в правом верхнем углу находим кнопку <kbd>начать</kbd>, жмем, выполняем инструкции и попадаем в панель управления приложением.

Далее `Настройки(Settings)` -> `Основное(Basic)`. Внизу видим кнопку <kbd>+ Добавить платформу(+ Add platform)</kbd>. Жмем. Добавляем `Android`. В поле `Название пакета Google Play(Google Play package name)` вводим свой `package` (пример `io.github.ziginsider.facebooksdkdemo`). В поле `Название класса(Class name)` полное имя класса `Activity` (пример `io.github.ziginsider.facebooksdkdemo.MainActivity`). В поле Ключевые `хэш-адреса(Key Hashes)` вводим полученный ранее `Key Hash`.

[image: enter Key Hash]

Сохраняем изменения.

**10)** Далее берем `Идентификатор приложения(App ID)` и записываем его в значения `res/values/strings.xml`. Например:

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">383374132098267</string>
<string name="facebook_login_protocol_scheme">fb383374132098267</string>
```

Во второй строке, просто добавляем “fb” перед идентификатором.

Теперь ваше приложение может работать с Facebook.

Подробнее: [небольшой туториал](https://ziginsider.github.io/Facebook_SDK_Login/) на русском языке по работе с Facebook SDK.

Comment: Добрый день, теперь вроде Facebook изменил сайт, можете обновить инструкцию по работе с ними?

Comment: День добрый. Давно не работал с Facebook SDK, а быстрый взгляд не выявил каких-либо существенных отличий от данной инструкции. Не могли бы вы указать, в чем заключаются конкретные несоответствия?

Comment: Спасибо за инструкцию! Единственный момент, что HASH ключ так получить можно в дебаге, и он не будет соответствовать релизному ключу подписи. Надо добавить еще шаг, как в build.gradle прописать автоматическую сборку релиза с ключом для публикации.